# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'data' of 'undefined' as it is undefined in covid tracker app

Tags: reactjs, function, dictionary, leaflet

I am making a covid tracker. In a particular function, i need to map data. But i get the following error TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'data' of 'undefined' as it is undefined. I am new to react and am having a hard time figuring this out. I have attached the error screenshot and code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhc0x.png)

```
export const ShowDataOnMap = ({data, casesType = "cases"}) =>
  data.map((country) => (
    <Circle
          center={[country.countryInfo.lat, country.countryInfo.long]}
          fillOpacity={0.4}
          pathOptions={casesTypeColors[casesType].option}
          radius={
            Math.sqrt(country[casesType]) * casesTypeColors[casesType].multiplier
          }
        >
      <Popup>
        <div className="info-container">
          <div
            className="info-flag"
            style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${country.countryInfo.flag})` }}
          ></div>
          <div className="info-name">{country.country}</div>
          <div className="info-confirmed">
            Cases: {numeral(country.cases).format("0,0")}
          </div>
          <div className="info-recovered">
            Recovered: {numeral(country.recovered).format("0,0")}
          </div>
          <div className="info-deaths">
            Deaths: {numeral(country.deaths).format("0,0")}
          </div>
        </div>
      </Popup>
    </Circle>
  ));
```

Comment: the problem is in your function signature `({ data, casesType = "cases" })`, the error is telling you that whatever is calling your `ShowDataOnMap` function is not passing an object that contains the property `data`. (ex. `response.data`)

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you are using `ShowDataOnMap` you would be passing data in props, before passing data there make sure that it is not empty/undefined.